# How to avoid NoSuchMethodException with primitives in Java

Tags: java, reflection

I'm working on legacy project and I've trapped into situation when I have to make additional init stuff with action object. In this code `AdmAction` is a basic interface and inside method I could have any of it's implementation. Some of implementations require additional properties must be initialized with values from `utilParams`.

```
private void initActionParams(AdmAction action, Map<String, Object> utilParams) {
    if (utilParams == null) {
      return;
    }
    utilParams.forEach((paramName, value) -> {
        try {
          Method setterMethod = action.getClass().getMethod(setterFor(paramName), value.getClass());
          setterMethod.invoke(action, value);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
          log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
          throw new WebApplicationException(e, Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
   });
}
```

`utilParams` looks like `"serviceId": 10` of `"ticketId": "8a30f5a7-809c-4551-8833-c2a60e4c6fd9"`.
Code works fine when value is an Object type (String, Integer etc.) and when setter method of `AdmAction` implementation consumes the same.
But there's one problem when I've got for example `Integer` type in `utilParams` and setter method in `action` which consumes `int`.
Of course code throws `NoSuchMethodException`

Example:
Action impl:

```
public class Foo implements AdmAction {
    // ...
    public void setServiceId(int serviceId) {
        this.serviceId = serviceId;
    }
}
```

Causes an exception.

I've tried to improve code with method search:

```
private void initActionParams(AdmAction action, Map<String, Object> utilParams) {
    if (utilParams == null) {
      return;
    }
    utilParams.forEach((paramName, value) -> {
        try {
            Method setterMethod = Arrays.stream(action.getClass().getDeclaredMethods())
                .filter((Method method) -> method.getName().equals(setterFor(paramName)))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(NoSuchMethodException::new);
            setterMethod.invoke(action, value);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new WebApplicationException(e, Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    });
```

I guess it's a little bit brute for actual case.
Can anybody help me find the way to write better and more aesthetic code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`java.beans.Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/beans/Statement.html) for this, which will do unboxing.

```
java.beans.Statement(action, setterFor(paramName), new Object[] {value})
    .execute();
```